# Visibility of object constants

Tags: php, oop, visibility, constants

I found out that object constants in PHP always have public visibility so it is not possible to set them to protected or private like this:

```
<?php
class MyClass {
    protected const constant = "this won't work";
}
?>
```

What's the explanation for this? I can't think of a good reason to force constants to be public.

Comment: *(related)* http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=27022

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a rather philosophical question, which is discussed in the [comments for Class constants in the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php). The argument seems to be that *[Visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) identifies who has the right to change members, not who has the right to read them*. Since constants cannot be changed, there is no point in having them support visibility when visibility is understood as access modifiers. If you follow that argumentation or go with [the linked feature request below your question](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=27022) is up to you.

Comment: @Pekka yeah, I am undecided on which to follow. I can see uses for constants having visibility but then again, it's nothing I ever felt strongly about. Constants are constants and if I need visibility I use properties.

Comment: yeah, I too think it's not a big deal either way (although it's interesting). But the argument that "visibility controls the right to *write* " doesn't make sense to me at all. That sounds plain wrong to me.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't think of a good reason to force constants to be public.

Well, constants are *static* definitions, bound to the *class* and not instantiated *objects*. They can be addressed only using `classname::constname`, and they cannot be altered. It stands to reason they are part of the blueprint of a class, and thus it doesn't really make sense to apply visibility rules to them.

That's just my rather subjective opinion, though. Interested to see whether anything based on hard OOP theory comes up.

Comment: Hmm, shouldnt static class members be always public by that definition, too?